# Identify when users are going to or have crossed a street. Android development

Tags: android, gps, location

I work in a research lab and I am creating my first app. I need to be able to identify if users are about to cross a street or if they have just crossed a street. Is this possible in Android studio?

I have found nothing in the google documentation for the maps api that seems to relate to what I need to do. I've also watched quite a few youtube videos on mapping coordinates.

I want to be able to record if a pedestrian was distracted(using their phone) while crossing a street. It also needs to run in the background of the users phone. Alerting them before they cross a street would be an added bonus. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google Maps API and save the name of the current street in a local DB. Then you could check on every change of the GPS location if the streetname you got from google has changed.
With this method you couldn't recognize when the user just changes the side of the street but you could track crossroads for example.

Comment: That's a darn good suggestion. I am a total noob coding outside of unity, even the idea of a local database is beyond what I could have came up with. Thanks!